# download is not working while download profilepic from google+

Tags: php, download, header, php-5.6

Here i am having google+ image propic url `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s6QeMfcJfdA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/p4PXN5-Z6KE/photo.jpg?sz=50`, now i want to download this pic and move to one folder, i tried to download but download is happening but image is not getting display ,it is showing empty file, if anyone means kindly update my code

```
    $data = file_get_contents('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s6QeMfcJfdA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/p4PXN5-Z6KE/photo.jpg?sz=50');
$filename ='image';
//header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
exit($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to download image, You also need to give extension like `.jpg` with file name. Also you are using php 5.6 so you should have set `verify_peer_name` to false: "verify_peer_name"=>false

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

```
$files_content_extra=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
$data = file_get_contents('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s6QeMfcJfdA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/p4PXN5-Z6KE/photo.jpg?sz=50', false, stream_context_create($files_content_extra));
$filename ='image.jpg'; // change this line
//header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
exit($data);
```

Comment: Now download is happening after that it is directly going to download folder instead od this i want to `move` under my project folder like `projectfolder/profilepic`

Comment: you are getting my question

Comment: You cant control download destination